# Android options menu. White strip top and bottom of menu

Tags: android, xml, customization

I am a noob wrt Android development.

[image]

How do you REMOVE or change the colour of the top and bottom strips of the options menu?
I have entered `<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/AraLightBlue</item>` into the 'themes.xml' file.
That works fine.

I created this style (square_menu.xml)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
    <padding
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
</shape>
```

and added

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/AraLightBlue</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/square_menu</item>
</style>
```

to themes.xml
and added
`app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTheme"`
to activity_main.xml.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the menu background you must create a style like this:

```
<style name="ThemeMenu.PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/ColorBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ColorText</item>
</style>
```

Then in the layout that contains the Toolbar to assign the header, you must apply the style.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeMenu.PopupTheme" />
```

If instead of changing the color, you want to add a custom background image, you can also do that by changing the style.

```
<style name="ThemeMenu.PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/ColorBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ColorText</item>
</style>
```

For example, I have defined this drawable, so that it takes the default background color according to the theme, and shows the menu below the header, assigning certain margins.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <padding
                android:top="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                />
            <solid android:color="@color/ColorBackground" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nySUN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use **solid** paramentr

Try this:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="your color"/>
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
    <padding
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: No change. White strips still present.

Comment: @tridiak have you sort this issue as I am facing same problem